# How to execute Firebug console JavaScript commands from terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, gruntjs, firebug

Is there a way to execute Firebug console JavaScript commands from the terminal? I need to execute multiple commands. My Firefox/Chrome browser crashes after running more than 100 commands.

Comment: To all closers, just because what he wants doesn't make a lot of sense, doesn't mean it isn't clear.

Comment: I think there's a bit of an X/Y issue here. Why is the browser crashing _"after running more than 100 commands"_?

Comment: And what, exactly, does "after running 100 commands" mean? Are you typing them each manually? Is it a loop? Is it a single file that has 100 statements/expressions in it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "Firebug console JavaScript commands"? JS statements or the Firebug [Console](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) or [Command Line API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API)? How do you run these "commands"? Is your browser crashing (browser window closes and [crash reporter dialog](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mozillacrashreporter) appears) or hanging (not reacting to user input anymore)?

Comment: I want to emulate the firebug console in the terminal. Is it theoretically possible ? By crash I mean, the browser stops responding, no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't run browser JavaScript on anything other than... a browser.

If you install **[NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)** you can use its JavaScript terminal, but you can't manipulate browser DOM through it for example.